# How to use Query cache with ADODB?

Tags: php, database, caching, adodb

How to use Query cache with ADOdb in PHP? Is it default in ADOdb or Is there any configuration needed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the cache directory, e.g.

```
$GLOBALS['ADODB_CACHE_DIR']=$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../cache/adodb';
```

Now you can use the Cache* methods like [CacheGetOne](http://phplens.com/lens/adodb/docs-adodb.htm#cachegetone) to get a cached result

```
$data = $rs->CacheGetOne($seconds_to_cache, $sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
CacheFlush($sql=false,$inputarr=false);
```

Comment: It's a bit difficult to tell what exactly is going on; is that a method definition from some documentation, and if so, for which class?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$ADODB_CACHE_DIR = 'db';
$_query = 'SELECT FROM table';
$recordSet = $conn->cacheExecute(2400,$_query);
```